# Python 3.7+: Access elements of a dictionary by order

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

So I understand that, since Python 3.7, dicts are ordered, but the documentation doesn't seem  to list methods of *using* said ordering. For example, how do I access say the first element of the dict by order, independent of keys? What operations can I do with the ordered dict?

As an example, I am working on implementing a Least Frequently Used cache, where I need to track not only the number of uses of a key, but also use Least Recently Used information as a tie break. I could use a dict of queues to implement a priority queue, but then I lose O(1) lookup within the queue. If I use a dict of dicts I can retain the advantages of a hashed set AND implement it as a priority queue... I think. I just need to be able to pop the first element of the dictionary. Alas, there is no dict.popleft().

For now I am converting the keys to a list and just using the first element of the list, but while this works (the dict *is* keeping ordering), the conversion is costly.

```
LFU_queue = collections.defaultdict(collections.defaultdict)
LFU_queue[1].update({"key_1":None})
LFU_queue[1].update({"key_32":None})
LFU_queue[1].update({"key_6":None})

#Inspecting this, I DO get what I expect, which is a 
#dict of dicts with the given ordering:
#{ 1: {"key_1":None}, {"key_32":None}, {"key_6":None}}

#here is where I'd love to be able to do something like
# LFU_queue[1].popleft() to return {"key_1":None}

list(LFU_queue[1])[0] works, but is less than ideal
```

Comment: Ordering in a dict _shouldn't matter_. If you're using dicts, you should not be thinking in terms of "the first element in the dictionary". Use a list of tuples (or an ordereddict as mentioned below) if you need that kind of behaviour.

Comment: As @Bharel says, OrderedDict has a direct way of doing the equivalent of `popleft`, though in Python >3.7 you can get the same with a plain dict. "A regular dict can emulate OrderedDict’s `od.popitem(last=False)` with `(k := next(iter(d)), d.pop(k))` which will return and remove the leftmost (first) item if it exists." (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

Comment: My understanding is that ordereddict is depricated and all dicts in python are now ordered dicts. I admit maybe I am going about this in a confused manner, but there must be a utility to dicts being ordered or it wouldnt be the standard right? This advice is basically "dont use the ordered nature of a dict, it is irrelevant".

Comment: @MisterNibbles it's true that OrderedDict is not now needed for some scenarios where it used to be, but it's not deprecated: the docs list some potential advantages of it. (e.g. "The OrderedDict algorithm can handle frequent reordering operations better than dict. As shown in the recipes below, this makes it suitable for implementing various kinds of LRU caches.") - https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects

Comment: @slothrop, SOLVED Ah! I was mistaken, and had thought that the current dict just subsumed the ordereddict functionality in its totality. I should just switch to ordereddict and that should solve it. Some vindication in the docs specifically calling out its utility in implementing LRU caches, exactly what I am trying to do (LFU being a flavor of LRU)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I disagree. The whole reason dict insertion-ordering was updated from implementation detail into a language requirement in 3.7+ is that it is incredibly _useful_. If this was a feature which shouldn't be relied upon, then they wouldn't have made it reliable.

Comment: In terms of your code logic, ordering in a dict shouldn't matter, even if it's _useful_ for things like serializating and deterministic iteration. Dictionary keys are not indices, they are keys.

Answer (score 0):

As others commented, using `OrderedDict` is the right choice for that problem. But you can also use the bare `dict` using the `items()` like this.

```
d = {}
d['a'] = 1
d['b'] = 2
first_pair = next(iter(d.items()), None)
```

If you are interested, see [PEP 372](https://peps.python.org/pep-0372/) and [PEP 468](https://peps.python.org/pep-0468/) for the history of dictionary ordering.

With PEP 468, you can implement a syntax sugar like this.

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_int, c_ulong

def c_fields(**kwargs):
    return list(kwargs.items())

class XClientMessageEvent(Structure):
    _fields_ = c_fields(
        type = c_int,
        serial = c_ulong,
        send_event = c_int,
        ...
    )
```